# physical energy definition for acoustic signals

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, acoustics

Recently I am reading Books "Signals and Systems" from Oppenheim and "Ultrasonic testing of materials" from Krautkrämer. In those books there are some definitions about wave energy:

- In the book of Oppenheim, it is written that the signal energy is defined as summed squares of amplitudes.
- In the book of Krautkrämer, the wave energy of plane and spherical waves is related to squares of amplitude not only, but also to e.g., acoustic impedance and signal frequency.

So now I am wondering if the definition of Oppenheim is simplified or which one represents the real physical scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oppenheim's definition is not so much simplified as it is context-specific:

His definition is primarily conceptual and is used to analyze and process signals in terms of their **mathematical properties**, and as such it accurately represents the energy of a signal within the domain of signal processing mathematics.

In contrast, Krautkrämer's definition is more appropriate for physical applications involving wave propagation in media, where additional factors influence wave energy. In this context, the energy of a wave is not just a mathematical abstraction but a **physical quantity**. Here, the wave energy is indeed related to the square of the amplitude, but also to other physical properties like acoustic impedance and signal frequency. Acoustic impedance, for instance, is a property of the medium through which the wave travels and significantly affects how much energy the wave carries.

Both definitions are valid within their respective contexts.

Comment: Hi @Jdip, thanks for the reply. That answers my question well. I am currently dealing with some acoustic impedance stuff and suddenly remembered the definition by Oppenheim, which was more a mathematical definition. Glad with this clarified.

Answer (score 3):

Signal energy and physical energy are not the same thing. They are often related but the relationship between can be very complicated especially in acoustics.

Signal energy for a discrete signal is indeed defined as the sum the squares. The unit of signal energy are simply the square of the unit of the signal itself.

Physical energy is defined in a more complicated way (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy) which involves generally some physical equations. It's unit is Joule (J).

Let's look at a signal that has been measured with a microphone in a sound field. If it's properly calibrated the unit of the signal would be Pascal (Pa).  The sound field (as the name implies) is indeed a field, i.e. it's spatially distributed and the energy is spread around accordingly. At any one point in the sound field you can only determine the intensity.  This is defined as the product of sound pressure and particle velocity. If the point in the sound field is sufficiently far away from any boundary and a sound source, pressure and velocity are in phase with each other and the ratio is simply the free field impedance of the medium, which is the product of the speed of sound and the density, i.e.

$$Z_{air} = \rho \cdot c \approx 1.2 \frac{kg}{m^3} \cdot 344 \frac{m}{s} = 413 \frac{kg}{m^2s} \tag{1}$$

So in this case we can indeed derive the intensity from the squared signal averaged over time as

$$I(\overrightarrow{r}) = \frac{1}{N}\sum \frac{p^2(n,\overrightarrow{r})}{Z_{air} } \tag{2}$$

To get the total radiated power you would need to spatially integrate over a closed surface and to get the energy (finally) you would need to integrate over time as well.

Conclusion: measuring the radiated acoustic energy of a sound source is really quite complicated.

Comment: Hi @Hilmar, before you answered my question, i saw your name already a lot of times, cause you answered a lot questions in this forum in detail:) Thanks for the clarification. I would like to vote your answer but not enough reputation. The acoustic impedance in equation 1 is often referred to as characteristic acoustic impedance right? Imagine i have a ultrasonic transducer which sends longitudinal acoustic signal to a steel plate. To describe the wave propagation, which mode should one take, i.e. plane wave or spherical wave or cylindrical wave?

Comment: And the characteristic acoustic impedance should not only be dependent on the material itself but also the waves transmitted through right? Lets say if i have for the same material (e.g. steel) both plane waves and spherical waves transmitted, are their characteristic acoustic impedances the same?

Comment: that would probably be a better question for physics.stackexchange.com . I think a steel plate would be much more complicated since you have strong boundary conditions, standing waves and very strong modal behavior, so pressure and velocity will generally not be in phase.